# How do you construct a generic union case in an F# quotation?

Tags: f#, quotations

The following code fails:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
let (empty,cons) =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<List<_>>)
    |> (fun cases ->
        cases |> Array.find (fun c -> c.Name = "Empty"),
        cases |> Array.find (fun c -> c.Name = "Cons"))

let valuesToList values =
    values
    |> List.map (fun v -> Expr.Value(v))
    |> List.fold
        (fun l v -> Expr.NewUnionCase(cons, [v;l]))
        <@@ List.empty<int> @@>

[1;2;3]
|> valuesToList
```

with the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Type mismatch when building 'sum': incorrect argument type for an F# union. Expected 'System.Object', but received type 'System.Int32'.
```

How do I specify the generic parameter type of the Cons union case?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `GetUnionCases(typeof<List<_>>)`. The wildcard is being inferred as `obj`. Thus the error

> Expected 'System.Object', but received type 'System.Int32'.

Here's a working version.

```
let valuesToList (values: list<'a>) =
    let empty, cons =
        FSharpType.GetUnionCases(values.GetType())
        |> (fun cases ->
            cases |> Array.find (fun c -> c.Name = "Empty"),
            cases |> Array.find (fun c -> c.Name = "Cons"))
    values
    |> List.map Expr.Value
    |> List.fold
        (fun l v -> Expr.NewUnionCase(cons, [v;l]))
        <@@ List.empty<'a> @@>
```

Comment: Indeed. I'm within the context of a type provider :D

Comment: But that second overload of Value may well do the job.

Comment: Then you'll have to box the list elements: `[box 1; box 2; box 3]`

Comment: Unfortunately that would rather destroy the point of the exercise for me. I may have to use something else rather than a List. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: My explanation of the problem was wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Interesting. Of course, as 'a is provided it won't be known at compile time. I think that some reflection magic might be able to help there though.